# Category should be hide if there is no any subcategory under it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on category and sub-category structure but stucked in it, I want when we removed all subcategory then their respective Category should also be removed. Mean to say category will display only that category has some subcategory.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

```js
$('#col-result-1').click(function(e) {
    $('#result-1').fadeOut("slow");
});
$('#col-result-2').click(function(e) {
    $('#result-2').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('#col-result-3').click(function(e) {
    $('#result-3').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('#col-result-4').click(function(e) {
    $('#result-4').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('#col-result-5').click(function(e) {
    $('#result-5').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('#col-result-6').click(function(e) {
    $('#result-6').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('#col-result-7').click(function(e) {
    $('#result-7').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
.result{
    background: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin:10px 0;
}
.result h3 {
    float: left;
    color: #127498;
    font-size: 16px;

}
.result .close-result {
   float: right;
    cursor; pointer;
}
.clear{ clear:both}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <div>
       <h2>Category Name</h2>
                 
       <div class="result" id="result-1">
                 <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
                 <p class="close-result" id="col-result-1">Close</p>
                 <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
                 
       <div class="result" id="result-2">
                 <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
                 <p class="close-result" id="col-result-2">Close</p>
                 <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="result" id="result-3">
                 <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
                 <p class="close-result" id="col-result-3">Close</p>
                 <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>

    </div>
     
     <div>
           <h2>Category Name</h2>
               
            <div class="result" id="result-4">
                     <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
                     <p class="close-result" id="col-result-4">Close</p>
                     <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>
    

        <div class="result" id="result-5">
                     <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
                     <p class="close-result" id="col-result-5">Close</p>
                     <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>

     </div>
     
     <div>
           <h2>Category Name</h2>
               <div class="result" id="result-6">
                   <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
                   <p class="close-result" id="col-result-6">Close</p>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
               </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the *remove* button is clicked, navigate up to the overall parent container and see if it has any remaining `.result` divs. If not,then remove the parent container.

```
$('.close-result').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.result').fadeOut('slow');
  if ($(this).closest('div:has(h2)').find('.result:visible').length == 1) {
    $(this).closest('div:has(h2)').remove();
  }
});
```

```js
$('.close-result').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.result').fadeOut('slow');
  if ($(this).closest('div:has(h2)').find('.result:visible').length == 1) {
    $(this).closest('div:has(h2)').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.result {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.result h3 {
  float: left;
  color: #127498;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.result .close-result {
  float: right;
  cursor;
  pointer;
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>Category Name</h2>

  <div class="result" id="result-1">
    <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
    <p class="close-result" id="col-result-1">Close</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="result" id="result-2">
    <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
    <p class="close-result" id="col-result-2">Close</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="result" id="result-3">
    <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
    <p class="close-result" id="col-result-3">Close</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div>
  <h2>Category Name</h2>

  <div class="result" id="result-4">
    <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
    <p class="close-result" id="col-result-4">Close</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="result" id="result-5">
    <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
    <p class="close-result" id="col-result-5">Close</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div>
  <h2>Category Name</h2>
  <div class="result" id="result-6">
    <h3>Sub Category Name</h3>
    <p class="close-result" id="col-result-6">Close</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I refactored your javascript click handling to use classes rather than ids as this greatly reduces the code.